# Flutter PersistentFooterButtons invisible with active keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I feel like I'm not completely getting *persistentFooterButtons*. I thought that they'd be part of the safe area, so I can see them when the keyboard is visible. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Persisting test'),
  ),
  body: Center(child: TextFormField()),
  persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.map), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.view_week), onPressed: () {}),
  ],
);
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `Stack` and an `Align` widget

```
  return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Persisting test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.map), onPressed: () {}),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.view_week), onPressed: () {}),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
      );
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that first but it didn't seemed "right" when I discovered persistentFooterButtons. :-D

Comment: the problem with this design is that it's not responsive. If you need to add more elements to the body and make everything scrollable you'll face some issues

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may help

```
  Widget bodySection = new Expanded(
    child: new Container (
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.white70,
      child:  new TextFormField(
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, 
                    ),
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      icon: new Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Enter some text here ..",
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12.0),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20.0, right: 5.0, bottom: 20.0, left:30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
    ),
  );

  Widget fixedBottomSection = new Container (
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    color:  Colors.purpleAccent[200],
    height: 48.0,
    child: 
    new InkWell(
      onTap: _continue,
      child:  new Center(
        child: new Text('Next ' , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      ),
    )
  );

  Widget content = new Column(
    // This makes each child fill the full width of the screen
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      bodySection,
      fixedBottomSection,
    ],
  );

  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      // backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent[200],
      title: new Text("Fixed bottom action bar above keyboard"),
    ),
    body: new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 0.0),
      child: content,
    ),
  );
```

here is a prove that it works:
[image: Fixed content above keyboard when focus on input]

Comment: When I use this code in my test szenario, it doesn't work either. You can't see the button with an opened keyboard. :(

Comment: @aksn i updated the sample and  it's work i tested it .

Comment: you can put whatever you need instead of the `Next` button .

Comment: Answer does not address `persistentFooterButtons`